# What is the use of the class in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

This is app.component.ts of angular tour of hero tutorial

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero{
 name : string;
 id : number;
}

const HEROES : Hero[] = [
    {name : 'jhon snow', id : 1},
    {name : 'wiz kahlifa',id : 2},
    {name : 'superman',id : 3},
    {name : 'batman',id : 4},
    {name : 'supersyian', id : 5}
];
```

I was wondering how the class work in type script i checked out app.component.js and saw the following line of code

```
var Hero = (function () {
 function Hero() {
 }
 return Hero;
}());
exports.Hero = Hero;
var HEROES = [
 { name: 'jhon snow', id: 1 },
 { name: 'wiz kahlifa', id: 2 },
 { name: 'superman', id: 3 },
 { name: 'batman', id: 4 },
 { name: 'supersyian', id: 5 }
];
```

I am not able to understand the use of class as in the app.component.js there is no link between the HEROES array and the Hero class i created in app.component.ts

Comment: That's because typescript is converting into javascript. You should read more about typescript and javascript in general.

Comment: The class allows for compile time checking. If one of the fields in the array was missing at compile time, you'd get an error.

Comment: The purpose of TypeScript is to add types. JS doesn't support the same type mechanism as TypeScript; once it's transpiled the TypeScript stuff is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to understand the use of class as in the `app.component.js` there is no link between the `HEROES` array and the Hero class i created in `app.component.ts`

You're right. It should. I suggest to not focus on the compiled code for old browsers. You could compile for modern JavaScript engine: the keyword `class` would remain and your question would still remain too.

The following code declares an ES6 class (with TypeScript syntactic sugar):

```
export class Hero {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

Then, the only way to instantiate the class is with the `new` operator:

> However, you can only invoke a class via `new` ([source: exploringjs from Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#sec_essentials-classes))

The following code is **misleading**:

```
const HEROES : Hero[] = [
  {name : 'jhon snow', id : 1},
  {name : 'wiz kahlifa',id : 2},
  // ...
];
```

It declares an array of type `Hero[]`. But the constructor is not executed. It is filled with objects that are not instances of the class.

## Valid ways

With an interface:

```
export interface Hero {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
const HEROES : Hero[] = [
  {name : 'jhon snow', id : 1},
  {name : 'wiz kahlifa', id : 2},
  // ...
];
```

With a class:

```
export class Hero {
  constructor (public name: string, public id: number) {
  }
}
const HEROES : Hero[] = [
  new Hero('jhon snow', 1),
  new Hero('wiz kahlifa', 2),
  // ...
];
```

Comment: That is a type script class not a ES6 Class.

Comment: @Nothing Just read [the official Web site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/): _"TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript"_. A TS class _is_ an ES6 class.

Comment: No you misunderstand what they mean by superset. Find me a ES6 Interpreter that won't complain about that code.

Comment: @Nothing Uh! TypeScript is JavaScript with syntactic sugar. The syntactic sugar cannot be parsed by a JavaScript engine. Classes in TypeScript are ES6 classes with syntactic sugar. I don't know how to explain. The official documentation [relies to ES6 classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html): _"Starting with ECMAScript 2015, also known as ECMAScript 6, JavaScript programmers will be able to build their applications using this object-oriented class-based approach."_

Comment: You are also miss using the term syntactic sugar. ECMAScript 6 uses syntactic sugar for classes that underneath behave exactly like ECMAScript 5 prototypes. Typescript still has to be transpilled making it another language.

Comment: I'm not Trolling, but it should be clear to new developers reading that ES6 Classes and TypeScript classes are Different. You cannot write a TypeScript Class today in hopes that it will be able to be interpreted by Chrome/IE in a year or two. If you write a ES6 Class Today it can already be understood by node 6+ and any recent version of chrome. A type script class will likely never be understood by any major Browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141575/discussion-between-paleo-and-nothing).

Answer (score 0):

So the Transpiler here is converting the Type script class into javascript 5 or ES5 compatible code. In ES5 you don't use class syntax when defining "classes" you use function syntax. for example

```
function car() { } //This defines a "class" called car but it doesnt do anything yet

//This defines a function of car that returns the max speed
car.prototype.maxSpeed = function() {
 return "70 MPH";
}
```

As you can see, there are no types here because javascript is dynamically typed. Nothing needs to be declared yet after the class is declared.

In your example you don't see Name and ID because those are used for compile time error checking in typescript. They wouldn't exist in their javascript transpilled classes.

As for your const heroes. Those are just javascript objects that take the shape your class would take in javascript after it is instantiated.